What is the recommended way to process large Spark DataFrames in chunks: `toPandas()` or `RDD.foreachPartition()`?
I am working with large datasets using PySpark and need to process my data in chunks of 500 records each. I am contemplating between converting my Spark DataFrames to Pandas DataFrames using toPandas() for easy chunking or sticking with Spark RDDs and using foreachPartition() to manually handle the chunking.
Here are the sample approaches I am considering.
Option 1: Converting to Pandas DataFrame
batch_size = 500    
# Convert Spark DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame for easier manipulation in chunks    
pd_df = df.toPandas()    
  
# Iterate through data in batches of 500    
for start_idx in range(0, len(pd_df), batch_size):    
    chunk = pd_df.iloc[start_idx:start_idx + batch_size]    
    do_something(chunk)    

Option 2: Using RDD’s foreachPartition
import itertools  
  
def process_partition(iterator):  
    chunk_size = 500  
    # Use itertools.islice to handle chunking  
    while True:  
        chunk = list(itertools.islice(iterator, chunk_size))  
        if not chunk:  
            break  # Exit loop if no more data to process  
        do_something(chunk)  # Process each chunk  
  

df.rdd.foreachPartition(process_partition)  

I am looking for advice on which approach might be more efficient and suitable for handling large datasets in a distributed environment. Or are there any other recommended solutions?
Please advise. Thanks!!

Why chunks of 500? What prevents you from running it in pyspark?

We need to invoke our dependencies in a rate-limited manner.

I added a benchmark test for both approaches on a ~1200 rows dataset
Using RDD’s foreachPartition:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from ISLP import load_data
import timeit
import itertools
import psutil
import os

process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
base_memory_usage = process.memory_info().rss


market_data_pd = load_data('Smarket')

spark_session = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("example") \
    .getOrCreate()

market_data_pd.iteritems = market_data_pd.items
df = spark_session.createDataFrame(market_data_pd)

start = timeit.default_timer()

def process_partition(iterator):
    chunk_size = 500
    # Use itertools.islice to handle chunking
    while True:
        chunk = list(itertools.islice(iterator, chunk_size))
        if not chunk:
            break  # Exit loop if no more data to process

df.rdd.foreachPartition(process_partition)

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)

memory_usage = process.memory_info().rss
print('Memory Usage: ', memory_usage - base_memory_usage)

Which returns output
Time:  2.043823186                                                              
Memory Usage:  3391488

Converting to Pandas DataFrame
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from ISLP import load_data
import timeit

import psutil
import os

process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
base_memory_usage = process.memory_info().rss

market_data_pd = load_data('Smarket')

spark_session = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("example") \
    .getOrCreate()

market_data_pd.iteritems = market_data_pd.items
df = spark_session.createDataFrame(market_data_pd)

start = timeit.default_timer()

batch_size = 500    
# Convert Spark DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame for easier manipulation in chunks    
pd_df = df.toPandas()    
  
# Iterate through data in batches of 500    
for start_idx in range(0, len(pd_df), batch_size):    
    chunk = pd_df.iloc[start_idx:start_idx + batch_size]  

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)

memory_usage = process.memory_info().rss
print('Memory Usage: ', memory_usage - base_memory_usage)

This returns
Time:  1.946675614                                                              
Memory Usage:  3731456

Looks like foreachPartition runtime is longer than toPandas but it is more memory efficient so it might depend on whether you need to optimize either memory or runtime

Thanks!! Really inspiring.
My use case is like over 288,000,000 rows per hour. So I'm not sure if that size can make any differences if we can't fully leverage the distributed nature of spark data frame.

@yuanb10 I see, 288,000,000 rows per hour is too large it might be better to optimize for memory since there's a limit for Spark executor and Python process in general but yes, partitioning data to multiple nodes in spark to process in parallel is always needed for large data
